# I wanna know counter example of this infinite sequence statement

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-groups

if ${a_{kn}}$ coverges for all integer $2\leq k$, then sequence $a_{n}$ converges.($n=1,2,3...$)

This infinite sequence statement is maybe False. I'm trying to find counter example of this.
Is there counter example of this statement?

(This is from Stewart's Calculus: Early Transcendentals)

Comment: Well, that was fun while it lasted.

Comment: There is at most one integer 2 that is less than $k$. I just wanna say that.

Comment: Would editing  $\forall k\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$ be a legal act? Or $\forall k\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$ depending on the convention in the OP's country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One counterexample (due to Euclid...!) is
$\displaystyle
a_n = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if $n$ is prime}, \\
0, &\text{if $n$ is not prime}.
\end{cases}
$

Comment: extraordinary.... I never thought of that.

Comment: Would the _Dirichlet' s function_,  restricted on the set of all algebraic real numbers, work as an counter-example, too?